# ESP32 WROOM32E module measuring its supply voltage

Tags: power-supply, adc, esp32

Can the ESP32 WROOM-32E module measure its 3.3 V supply voltage using its internal ADCs?
Update 1: Can the measurement be done internally without an external voltage divider. Asking since I am maxed on usage of the ADC pins.

Comment: Just use two lines in Arduino ? You can use the "sketch", it is here:  https://www.letscontrolit.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=130

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the ESP32 includes any internal supply voltage monitor. You would have to use an external pin and the ADC. There is a programmable brownout detector, but it can't be used in this manner. So I think the answer to your (edited) question is unfortunately "no."

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: yes.

You just have to scale it to bring down to 0..Vref range, where Vref is usually 1.1V but you need to check datasheet for your particular chip. For scaling you can use plain voltage divider, or a combination of a divider and [internal attenuation](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/v4.4.2/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/adc.html).

Furthermore, the ULP coprocessor can also [measure voltage](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/4b6d9c8ad3/examples/system/ulp_fsm/ulp_adc) while in sleep mode.

BTW, this seems to be a duplicate question. Stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56833346/10627427) without even looking for one.

Comment: It would be interesting to measure the adc result with a changing vcc of the esp32. Like 2.8-3,5 volts.

Comment: @RemyHx technically, you are asking about stability of the internal reference. I did not find any ppm in the datasheets, but they do claim down to 23mV with calibration, which corresponds to 2% accuracy.

Comment: it’s interesting to measure. Planning to do tomorrow, because I’m interested in the result for a project.

Comment: As mentioned in the update, I'm asking if supply measurement can be done without an external voltage divider.

Comment: Some ESP32 chips can use ADC to sample VDD33 via internal connection. The SDK even provides a function for it, something like system_get_vdd33(). However I saw posts claiming that although it worked fine on ESP8266 it does not anymore on newer chips. I guess it is up to you to find whether they have a replacement function and if the chip supports it. Note, that you most likely will need an attenuator configured to bring VDD to useful range