# Can I measure the battery voltage of an ESP without external resistors?

Tags: batteries, voltage-divider, esp8266, battery-operated, esp32

I have an ESP32 (and also an ESP8266) powered by 3 AA batteries.

I'd like to measure the battery voltage, to be able to inform the user of *"Low battery"*.

I think it can be done by doing a "voltage divider" to have a voltage between 0V and 1V (instead of 0V to 4.5V) and feed this into one of the device's ADC.

**Question: could this "battery measurement" be done *without* any external resistor, and just the ESP32/ESP8266 (+ cables between pins, if needed)?**

References but without definitive solution:

- [How to measure battery voltage with internal adc ESP32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56833346/how-to-measure-battery-voltage-with-internal-adc-esp32)
- [Module ESP32 + OLED + batterie](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/module-esp32-oled-batterie/602714/100) which seems to show that `ESP.getVc()` is not reliable
- [Read internal Vcc voltage](https://www.letscontrolit.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=130)
- [ESP32 WROOM32E module measuring its supply voltage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/641188/esp32-wroom32e-module-measuring-its-supply-voltage?rq=1)

Comment: Well, as those MCUs would likely go up in smoke if powered from 4.5V batteries, you might want to describe if you mean modules with other components in addition to the MCU, or just the MCUs themselves. Usually, the answer would be just "no", but your module might be special.

Comment: @Justme They have a 5V input (this is where I feed 4.5V) which is converted to 3.3V if I remember correctly?

Comment: I still don't know if you are talking about a module with regulators and MCU, or the MCU itself. I have to guess the former, and then I don't know which module you have to figure out if the module has special inputs for measuring battery voltage higher than MCU supply. The MCU absolute maximum is 3.6V supply.

Comment: @Justme You guessed correctly :), a module with regulators and MCU, in my case Firebeetle ESP32 v1.

Comment: @Justme The manual covers a few applications (https://download.kamami.pl/p573315-FireBeetle%20Board-ESP32%20User%20Manual%20update.pdf, https://wiki.dfrobot.com/FireBeetle_ESP32_IOT_Microcontroller(V3.0)__Supports_Wi-Fi_&_Bluetooth__SKU__DFR0478) but I have found nothing about this particular one. I was wondering if there is a generic ESP32 / ESP8266 solution.

Comment: Good, so you have some board module product which contains regulators and other stuff, including an ESP32-WROOM module which contains a specific ESP32 chip. should have been mentioned in the question. Then what does the manual or schematics tell you about measuring voltages with it?

Comment: Ok I'll edit the question to include this @Justme, thanks! About measuring voltages, I haven't found anything specific to this application in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

Your module schematics already contains a resistor divider for measuring the battery voltage.

According to some people, the resistors may not be included on board.

So yes, you don't need any **external** resistors if you don't want to.

But the board **should** have a resistor divider for measuring battery voltage on a pin called "A0", but **if they are not present** you need to put resistors yourself, either externally to your module, or on the module where the resistors are missing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Can you give the link ("according to some people") with the details about where the resistors could be? About "A0", where is it connected to, with which possible resistor? If you have a link, it would be great, then I'll try to figure out how to connect to the ADC to measure voltage.

Comment: They are complaining about that on the product web page of the manufacturer of the product you have.